# Pinouts for OKX-T/5-D12N-C not on datasheet

Tags: dc-dc-converter, pinout

T/5-12N-C][1](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/murata-power-solutions-inc/OKX-T-5-D12N-C/811-2622-ND/3314280) 12v -> 5v DC-DC converter for a project so that I can power a solenoid and a RPi with a single power source.  Unfortunately, the [datasheet](https://power.murata.com/datasheet?/data/power/okx-t5-d12.pdf) doesn't list a pinout.

There are 5 pins, and I can locate pin 1 by the square solder target.  There should be Vin (12v), Switch On (12v), Trim, Vout(5v) and Gnd.

Is there a convention or standard that everyone should "just know", or is this an example of a part that should never have been made?

Comment: Look closer at the datasheet.

Comment: Thank you for your flippant commentary.  It was helpful to be told that I'm illiterate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at page 11 of that data sheet. There’s a table showing the pinout. In the same page, the mechanical drawings have the pin numbers listed.

Comment: Oh geez.  I must have looked past that a dozen times or more.  Thanks.